# Terik Grid Dropdown Column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I know that there are some examples from Telerik but I don't quite understnad them. You can see my code below. What am I doing wrong?

**Snippet of grid:**

```
.Columns(columns =>
            {
              columns.Bound(product => product.Id).Hidden();
              columns.Bound(product => product.KdNr);
              columns.Bound(product => product.Datum).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}");
              columns.Bound(product => product.Aktion);
              columns.Bound(product => product.Ergebnis).EditorTemplateName("ErgebnisTemplate.cshtml").Title("Ergebnis");
              columns.Bound(product => product.Wiedervorlage).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy H:mm}");
              columns.Bound(product => product.Bemerkung);
              columns.Bound(product => product.Erledigt).ClientTemplate(
                "<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled'" +
                    "# if (Erledigt) { #" +
                        "checked='checked'" +
                    "# } #" +
                "/>"
            );
```

Here you can see that the column "Ergebnis" which is the 5th column is bound to a custom template (`EditorTemplateName("ErgebnisTemplate.cshtml")`).

**ErgebnisTemplate.cshtml (located in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates):**

```
@using System.Collections
@model System.Int32

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem()
        {
          Text = "Anrufen",
          Value = "A"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
          Text = "Verloren",
          Value = "V"
        }
    })
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .Name("Ergebnis")
)
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much, that simple step did it!! put it as answer @AmalDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the .cshtml extension while specifying EditorTemplateName. Just EditorTemplateName("ErgebnisTemplate") is enough.

Since MVC is following conventions over configuration approach, it will automatically search for the razor file with the name provided in the `EditorTemplateName` method under the views folder

Comment: Can you hepl me with one other thing? When I select an element of the dropdown and save it, the value is empty... Is it because I haven't linked up something correctly?

Comment: Can you please post the action method and the razor snippet from wereu are calling the save method